# Conflicting versions of MySql.Data.dll in .Net project not allowing me to add/edit TableAdapters in my DataSets

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dataset, mysql-connector, tableadapter

I have a WinForms / .Net 4.0 application in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.
When I try to add, or edit, a TableAdapter in any of my DataSets, I get this error:

> The wizard detected the following problems when configuring the
>   TableAdapter:
>
> Details:
>
> Generated SELECT statement. [A]MySQL.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
>   cannot be cast to [B]MySQL.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection. Type A
>   originates from 'MySQL.Data Version 6.9.8.0,
>   Culture=neutral,PublicToken=c5687fc88969c44d' in context 'Default' at
>   location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\MySQL.Data.dll'. Type B originates from 'MySQL.Data, Version 6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' in context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySQL.Data\v4.0_6.9.9.0_c5687fc88969c44d\MySQL.Data.dll'.

Obviously it is complaining about two different versions of the MySQL.Data.dll 6.9.8 and 6.9.9. What I don't understand though is why or where is it referencing version 6.9.8.0? If I look at my project's references, it is using MySQL.Data.dll version 6.9.9.0. This is a NuGet package at location:

*C:\Users\Fabs-LenovoY70\Source\Workspaces\Tracker\Tracker\packages\MySql.Data.6.9.9\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll*

I've tried the solution at [[A]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection cannot be cast to [B]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605158/amysql-data-mysqlclient-mysqlconnection-cannot-be-cast-to-bmysql-data-mysqlc) but didn't work.

I've searched my entire solution for any references to 6.9.8 and I've found nothing. I've been Googling for a solution for a whole day now and have found nothing that's worked. :( Any ideas anyone? Thank you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am having the same issues with VS 2012.  I am not sure how to fix it but after spending quite a bit of time on it here is what I see is happening.

1. Over all your/my system is at mysql.data.dll version 6.9.9.0.  I am not able to downgrade this to 6.9.8.0  When I do I create other version problems with  mysql.data.dll that seem to be unresolveable with my knowledge level.
2. I chased down all 6.9.8.0 versions of the DLL and removed them, ensuring that there was a 6.9.9 version in its place. Once I have done this I am not able to add a data connection to a MySQL Database. When I try I get the error *An error occurred that is normally caused by not having Visual Studio properly installed*.  In addition non of the previously defined data connections work.
3. Not having MYSQL-connector-net-6.9.9 installed gives an error of "Cannot obtain provider factory for data provider named MySql.Data.MySqlClient" and you don't even get to the error described above by the OP.

   4. I have tried various connector-net versions and this does not fix the problem.

I have no references to 6.9.8.0 in any of my projects but clearly for some reason VS needs it to create the data connections.

Update:

I removed MySQL, then went through and deleted all mysql*.dll and all config files.   I then used the MySQL Installer 5.7.14  found at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

The installer still installed the   mysql.data.dll version 6.9.8.0 and it still causes the error.

Update:
The problem is with MySQL Connector / Net.   It is using version 6.9.9.0 of the DLL and everything else is using 6.9.8.0   Go to your community installer and uninstall connector / net.   Then go to https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/ and get version 6.9.8 of the connector / net.  Install this and everything should be fine.   It has worked on my system.

Comment: Created Bug Report With MySQL.  It can be found at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82617&thanks=2&notify=3

Comment: Thanks for the answer BrownPony!  This helped me get past the MySQL DB connection error.  I wish this answer would be accepted as "correct".

Comment: Yes uninstalling 6.9.9 and installing 6.9.8 worked for me

Comment: Man I've been struggling with this for 4 days, every times I was fixing an issue another came, but I think now it is good !!!! I kinda love you hahahaha <3

Comment: @Roxy'Pro  I am not sure what the fix would be when MySQL was shipping a faulty install program.

Comment: And here we are in exactly the same place with the mysql version 8.0.16.0.  Do the people at MySql even test these install programs.   Its such a pita that it is almost criminal.   I have already wasted 10 hrs on this and now it looks like I will try going back to 6.9.8

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling 6.9.9 and installing 6.9.8 worked for me. I had uninstallation problems and I had to use this tool from microsoft to clear the connector install/uninstall problem 
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed
Finally I had to make sure that mysql.data.dll referenced is version 6.9.8. I guess it's the only solution after spending countless hours up and down.

Comment: Yes uninstalling 6.9.9 and installing 6.9.8 worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check your app.config (or web.config) files. I had to downgrade from 6.10.8 to 6.10.7 .Net Connector. I wiped all the 6.10.8 version dlls from my system, rebuilt the project and it was still asking for 6.10.8. When you downgrade a Nuget package in Visual Studio, the .config is not altered - it was still at 6.10.8. I changed it to 6.10.7 and everything worked.